# check table in auth::attempt laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect to different page where auth::attempt is true. I have tables

```
unique(id, password, id_book)
book(id_book, name, author,...)
unnnique.id_book = book.id_book
```

id and password for login, if auth::attempt is true, redirect to 'input' form page
for register book when $book->save, unique.id_book will update with book.id, and when the book was registered, if login again with same username and password will redirect to 'detail'. 'detail' is detail from book what inserted on form registration like name, author, ...

```
if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
if(...){
return Redirect::to('detail');
}
else{
return Redirect::to('input');
}}
else{
return Redirect::to('/')->with('msg', 'Login failed, username or password worng');
}
```

models/unique.php

```
class Unique extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
//table name
protected $table = 'unique';
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}
public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}

}
```

How to check this? I use laravel 4.2

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what the conditions for a redirect to `detail` are. Can you please try to explain that a bit clearer?

Comment: @lukasgeiter 'detail' is detail page from book who login and registering it, like name, author, ...

Comment: Okay now I understand... Do you use Eloquent models? And if yes, could you please post your user model (`unique`)?